# Set UIImageView height proportional to width in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to make a `UITableView` where each cell contains either a portrait or landscape `UIImageView`, where the images keep their aspect ratio while filling the width of the screen, like this:

```
|        |
|########|
|########|
|########|
|########|
|########|
|        |
|########|
|########|
|########|
|        |
```

I've set autolayout constraints to attach the `UIImageView`'s edges to the table view cell's `contentView`. This works for width, but the height isn't what I want - it always expands to the full height of the underlying image.

I have these settings on the table view:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

When constructing the cell, I'm trying to calculate the necessary height so I can change the frame (or height constraint) of the `UIImageView`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("activityPostCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
let image = UIImage(named: "my-image.jpg")
let aspectRatio = image!.size.height / image!.size.width

let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(15) as UIImageView        
let imageViewHeight = aspectRatio * imageView.frame.width
```

The problem here is that the `imageView.frame` I get is *before* layout has occurred, so I'm not computing the correct height anyway.

Am I going about this the right way? Is there an easy way to set a `UIImageView`'s aspect ratio to match the image it contains? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at using an aspect ratio constraint on the image view?

Comment: Yes that did the trick, thank you. I'll add my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per @Wain's suggestion, adding an aspect ratio constraint solved the problem:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my-image.jpg")
let aspectRatio = image!.size.height / image!.size.width

let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(15) as UIImageView

imageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: imageView, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
    toItem: imageView, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 
    multiplier: aspectRatio, 
    constant: 0)
)
```

Comment: how will you call the uiviewcontroller to refresh its contents? such as on a uitableviewcell ?